# Elastic Beanstalk configuration with Load Balancer, Nginx, and SSL for socket.io

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nginx, websocket

I am trying to configure my Elastic Beanstalk environment to work correctly with socket.io using a Load Balancer, Nginx, and an SSL certificate. However, I am having trouble getting WebSockets (WSS) to be accessible.

This is the error:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=OpfeVwdRsdm8Wt76AAAC' failed:

Here's part of my app.js code:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: origins,
    methods:  ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true
  }
});

realtime.realtime(io);

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log('listening on *: 3000');
});
```

I have tried multiple configurations, but I cannot get WSS to work correctly. Attached are the images with the current configuration of my Elastic Beanstalk environment: [Image 1], [Image 2], [Image 3].

My questions are:

What is the correct Load Balancer configuration to enable secure (WSS) traffic in socket.io?
What adjustments should I make to the Nginx configuration to work correctly with socket.io and secure WebSockets?

Is there any additional Elastic Beanstalk configuration I should consider to make everything work properly?

I appreciate any help or advice in solving this issue. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

IN LOCALHOST WORKS BUT IN PRODUCTION NOT :(